# Can I apply for a US visit visa from Pakistan while my immigration visa CR1 is still pending?

Tags: visas, usa, pakistani-citizens, spouses

I married a US citizen in South Africa on January 25, 2016. She then hired an immigration lawyer in the USA to apply for a CR1 Spousal Visa. In August, the lawyer submitted an I-130 form but a decision is still pending. We are missing each other and she can't come to Pakistan because of her work commitments.

Can I apply for a visit visa to visit her for two weeks?

Comment: you can apply but most likely your application will be turned down because you are an intending immigrant. This is ver common in Pakistan, therefore simply wait till your visa number is availabe and apply as an immigrant

Comment: If you can meetup in Canada or Mexico, it is simply easier to meet-up in Pakistan for all concerned; PK-782 is a weekly (every Thursday) flight from Toronto to Islamabad (non-stop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can however you will likely be rejected by law under [214(b)](http://tehran.usembassy.gov/visas/214b-refusal.html). Showing immigration intent is typically a disqualifier for ordinary Visitor visas and you have already showed immigration intent with the CR1 filed for you. Visitor visas do not allow for dual intent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_intent

It is simpler to just wait under the cirumstances.